# Not able to add permission on category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, admin-panel, permissions

I have gone through document and can see that we can add permission to category without any plugin. Link: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/category-permissions.html

But I am not able to see Category permission option under:  Admin sidebar > Products > Categories.

Please help me with it.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have magento 2 enterprise edition ? because the link you have posted is for magento2 enterprise edition so please confirm ?

Comment: No, I am using open source of Magento 2. So is there any way I can get this functionality without plugins?

Comment: No there is no way , you need to developed your custom module for that , or else use third party extension.

Comment: ohh!  I am new to Magento. So I am just exploring options. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Category permission option only available in **Magento 2 EnterPrise
>   Edition (MCOM)**
>
> So if you are using **open source (Community edition)** Then you need to
>   use Third party extension or you need to built custom module.
>
> Hope it helps,

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in CE edition of M2 you must be an enterprise customer to use this functionality